# Hibernate: Do both merge and update via annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

I have three entities and related classes: BulkEmployee, BulkEmployeeRow and Department
BulkEmployeeRow contains an object of BulkEmployee and Department like this:

```
@ManyToOne
BulkEmployee bulkEmployee;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade(value = { CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
Department department
```

Now there is a UI where several employees can be created in bulk. This page has autosave feature so any change triggers hibernate saveOrUpdate

User can add several employee rows in the page. Each employee row has option to select a department from existing list of departments or they can fill a form to create a new department

Now the problem is that when user selects same department for more than one employee, it gives following exception:

> org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the
>   same identifier value was already associated with the session

If I change CascadeType of department to MERGE like below:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Cascade(value = { CascadeType.MERGE })
Department department
```

then selection of same department for different employees works fine but selecting a new department gives following exception:

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
>   transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:

Is there a way I can ask hibernate to do merge and then save via annotations only?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so its not possible to do via annotation I guess.

So, as suggested everywhere, I did

```
dao.merge(entity)
```

and then

```
dao.saveOrUpdate(entity)
```

to solve the issue